# Issue with increase local memory_limit

Tags: php, magento, server

sometimes I get issue:

```
Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 792723456 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 20480 bytes) in /home/mall/domains//vendor/magento/zendframework1/library/Zend/Db/Statement/Pdo.php on line 291
```

792723456 bytes roughly translate to 792 MB

I try increase memory limit. I set in `php.ini 2048M` but still `local value display: 756M` and `Master Value only correct 2048M` and still I get above issue. Any solution?

[image]

Comment: Looks like you've edited the wrong php.ini file. The webserver, for example apache2, uses a different one. Use phpinfo() to determine the real path.

Comment: did you restarted apache server after doing this. Also its depends upon your code-implementations as well, so may or may not this above solution you are trying will work

Comment: It mentions local value, so there may be another place where it is set. You can try `grep -R memory_limit *` from the root of your project to see if it's being set anywhere in that directory. Also check your .htaccess

Comment: Looks like there may be something somewhere overriding the value you set in the php.ini. Are you doing an override in PHPcode or is there a setting in the Virtual Host definition?

Comment: Thanks for all comments. im using litespeed web server. I first found php path  via command  /usr/local/bin/php --ini | grep 'Loaded Configuration File' and get result: Loaded Configuration File:         /usr/local/php74/lib/php.ini
 next I changed in this file memory_limit and after this  restart web server and  this changes is visible,   correct for master value, but I dont know what is local memory_limit and  how to change it because here display only 756M memory_limit in phpinfo

Comment: The MASTER value is from `php.ini` if the LOCAL value is different, then it has been changed as mentioned above

Comment: @RiggsFolly thanks friend. This is your shot. I found a value in .htaccess that overwritten my change! Once again thanks!